# Convert Unix Executable to Windows Executable

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, unix, executable

I compiled and ran a C++ program using Eclipse on my MacBook Pro.  I now need to convert the Unix executable to a windows executable.  How do I go about this?  Specifally, how do I get this code to run on a Windows machine from the command prompt?

Comment: Do you have the source code available?

Comment: The conversion process is called "portable code" and "recompilation".

Comment: http://www.colinux.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can get the unix executable to run on a Windows system is using a virtual machine (Something like VMWare or VirtualBox). This isn't REALLY running it on Windows, of course, it's setting up a UNIX system on Windows and running it on that UNIX system.

The executables (and the needed runtime environment) are vastly different between the two systems, you can't just run executables from one on the other.

Your only other option is to setup Eclipse on your Windows system and compile the application there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "convert" an executable, you need to recompile for your target system. If you are using a GCC toolchain that is set up for Eclipse and there is no Mac specific code, it should be as easy as moving the project over, setting it up in Eclipse, and recompiling it. If that is too much of a hassle, you can consider setting up a `Makefile` and using MingW or Cygwin, or even Visual Studio if you'd like. If there is Mac specific code, then you need to look up the appropriate Windows documentation, or use something cross-platform like GTK+ or Qt.